# Can't enumerate controls in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, controls, enumeration

I have defined html table not with the asp-tags one in my `*.aspx` page. Then I have added some asp controls into this table in its rows as: `<asp:CheckBox>`.

I have defined a lot of checkboxes, because I need to provide for the user large amount of selections and I can't minimize the count of checkboxes.

In `CodeBehind` I wanted to enumerate the whole Controls to find, what I need by the `GetType().Name` and then added to temporary list for the future actions.

But I've got a trouble, in the debugger I can't see any checkbox and the amount of the controls is very small.

I'm enumerating the controls in page like this:

```
foreach (var item in Page.Controls)
{
    if (item.GetType().Name == "CheckBox")
    {
         CheckBox checkBox = item as CheckBox;

         if (checkBox.ID != null && checkBox.ID != String.Empty && checkBox.Checked)
         {
             arrayDocs.Add(checkBox.ID);
         }
    }
}
```

The full code of my page:

aspx: http://pastebin.com/gUs2LchL

code behind: http://pastebin.com/5tfnKJSt

Comment: If you want to enumerate _all_ the controls on the page you need to do it recursively.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Magnus recursively? 23 checkboxes, recursion does have repeated steps, try to imagine how could it be slow? even if you use tail-recursion, I suppose, that any control on the asp-page is in some Control-Container, which you can to enumerate with the foreach() block. The main Q of this topic is, that I can't link to the container which holds all checkboxes to enumerate them and also it can't be loaded from the main `Page.Controls` or `this.Controls`, which is rather stange. I suppose that checkboxes are in table server-side control, but I've tried to get elements - no success, the same result

Comment: @OlegOrlov At least you'll find out which container the checkboxes are in. And iterating the controls recursively should be quite fast unless you have millions of controls in the page. Try it and find out.

Comment: @Magnus look at the simple recursion scheme of its work: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/ru/b/b4/Treerecurs.jpg then image how will repeated calculations allocate memory for the simple iteration? for example to get some control iteratively you shall allocate 64 Kb/per one (just for the sample) if you have 6 controls then you shall load each control, in simple iterative you reallocate for each new control the same memory part in PC ( memory range ) with the recursion you are allocating for each new control on stack new part with the 64 kb size.

Comment: @Magnus so, iterating for the 6 controls won't you allocate new memory and also there would be less calculations, for the recursion method each control will be in memory till the cycle's end and make more steps. Too much cost for the elegant code, if it would be a simple recursion ( not tail one or corecursion )

Comment: The controls are already in memory. You can always do some memory profiling, but recursively iterating the controls on the page should not be costly. (This happens every time the page is rendered anyway)

Comment: @Magnus already? dynamic control are already in memory? you could add 10000 controls dynamically and you will say, that all 10000 controls were prepared in memory? dynamic controls, by the word "dynamic" mean that they would be allocated in memory dynamically and won't be stored earlier in memory. How could recursive iteration be not costly? if it generates at each its cycle the repeated steps on stack? it's the problem of recursion... and how could you use recursion in PageLoad() event? Don't some thread security models deny you from such actions?

Comment: As you'll see from my answer the only answer is to use recursion as @Magnus quite correctly stated, the page is built in memory before the HTML is rendered to the client so the cost is not as great as you fear - although it is obviously proportional to the number of controls on the page as you state. The memory cost here should only be that of the collection, which will be destroyed as it moves out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls.aspx) the Control.Controls property returns a collection of the **child** controls of that control, and not **descendants**. Only server side controls **directly** contained within that control will be part of the collection.

If you want to build a collection of all the controls on the page you will need to recursively loop through the controls to add their child controls and so on - as Magnus correctly stated.

The most efficient/performant way would be to build the collection from the parent container of the checkboxes, in this case the cells of HtmlTable "tableDocs".

Change-

```
foreach (var item in Page.Controls)
```

To-

```
foreach (var item in tableDocs.Controls)
```

Then you will need to recursively loop through the child controls to at least two levels (row -> cells -> checkboxes) before you get to the checkboxes.

What may be far more straightforward is to use generics and create a typed List of CheckBox containing all the checkboxes you wish to test.

Something like-

```
var checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>{checkboxAuctionHistory, checkboxBackSaldo, checkboxBalanceDecrypted}; //And so on

    foreach (var checkbox in checkboxes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(checkbox.ID) && checkbox.Checked)
            {
                arrayDocs.Add(checkbox.ID);
            }
        }
    }
```

This has an obvious flaw in that you need to remember to alter the list every time you add a new checkbox to the form.

Alternatively move the checkboxes out of a table or remove the runat="server" attribute from it, removing the table from the ASP.NET control tree, and making the container for the checkboxes "form1".

Most of the other markup on the page does not have runat="server" and therefore these elements are not part of the ASP.NET control tree.